# Docker compose creates network with different subnet each time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a simple yaml file which starts two containers: JBoss and Postgres. When I run:

```
docker-compose -f compose-application.yaml up -d
```

new network is created - this is what I expect. However, when I stop containers with:

```
docker-compose -f compose-application.yaml down
```

and start them once again then network gets new subnet (increased by 1). When restart is repeated few times then subnet assigned conflicts with already existing one (problem with routing etc.).

I know I can specify subnet which should be used inside yaml. However, I tried to run this on different machine (Docker for Windows 7) and there this network gets the same subnet each time.

I am using docker version:

```
docker version
Client:
Version:           18.06.1-ce
API version:       1.38
Go version:        go1.10.3
Git commit:        e68fc7a
Built:             Tue Aug 21 17:23:03 2018
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Experimental:      false

Server:
Engine:
  Version:          18.06.1-ce
  API version:      1.38 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.3
  Git commit:       e68fc7a
  Built:            Tue Aug 21 17:25:29 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

and docker compose:

```
docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306
docker-py version: 3.5.0
CPython version: 3.6.7
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
```

Comment: Was this solved somehow?

Comment: Creating the network with the APP_NAME_default name: "docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 APP_NAME_default" will cause "docker-compose up" to not to create a new network. Instead it will connect to the existing network with desired mask.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works differently in Windows 7, but I can imagine that's because Docker machine itself.

I think the best solution it's really define a network on docker-compose yml file. Something like this:

```
  networks:
    network_name:
      name: NETWORK_NAME
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: SUBNET
```